# HTML+CSS+JS game as a standalone Windows application

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The game works fine on a browser, however I would like to transform it into a standalone Windows application (an .exe file, in short).

I've tried using [this tool](https://www.davidesperalta.com/download/htmlcompiler), which indeed is able to output an .exe file from my project, however the game doesn't seem to react to click events. Note that this problem does not occur when I run the game on a browser.

What are some valid alternatives to generate an executable file from an HTML file and its dependencies (CSS sheets, JavaScript scripts, images, sounds, etc)?

Comment: You could possibly wrap it by Electron with React or Angular. Electron supports various Desktop-App but no Android-App so far. This will also add a bit more technologie you would need to learn.

Answer (score 1):

> In the strict sense you can't. HTML was mainly invented to design and
>   exchange documents written for a browser (and CSS provides layout
>   information for such a document).
>
> ---
>
> ...there is the possibility of creating an app outside of the browser;
>   but technically it is not an .exe ...

Link to the answer: [How can you convert HTML, CSS, and Javascript into a EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805353/how-can-you-convert-html-css-and-javascript-into-a-exe/#answer-21805514)

---

But the best way to do it (in my opinion) should be:

> - **Electron, by GitHub**. Lets you build cross-platform Windows, MacOS,    and Ubuntu applications from HTML/JavaScript/CSS. It works by
>     embedding them into a Chromium build alongside with Node.js. Many
>     applications such as Slack and Visual Studio code are built with
>     Electron.

Link to the post: [here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14797/can-you-convert-html-css-and-javascript-into-a-exe#answer-50666).

Comment: Your link is to a closed question that will hopefully now be deleted. Then you give opinion but asking for opinion, if that is what this question is doing, is not allowed . [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Since the question itself is off topic, you should vote to close it as such instead of answering it.

Comment: @Rob I didn't just want to send him to 5 years old closed question, where answers are based upon what was available at the time of writing. My "opinion" was about whether this solution is "the best" or not, "being the best" is never objective.

Comment: My real point is that the question is off topic and is up for closure and shouldn't be answered at all.

Comment: Good point. Already flagged it.